# How to use libcurl functions inside a Windows Forms Application in Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: visual-c++, curl, c++-cli, libcurl, windows-forms-designer

Here is the situation...

I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express.

I am trying to create a windows forms application that can load the source code of any given URL into a RichTextBox.  I wish to accomplish this using the cUrl library.  The good news is, after beating my brains out for more than 24 hours on how to properly link the libcurl.dll file to my project I was successful.  In fact I was able to use the cUrl library to retrieve the source of a url in a Windows console application and print the result to a command window.  So I do not have linking problems.

For reference, below is the source code for the main CPP file for the working test console app:

```
// MyApplication.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

int writer(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string *buffer);
string curl_httpget(const string &url);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << curl_httpget("http://www.google.com/") << endl;
}

string curl_httpget(const string &url)
{
    string buffer;

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode result;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str()  );
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);

        result = curl_easy_perform(curl);//http get performed

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);//must cleanup

        //error codes: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
        if (result == CURLE_OK)
        {
            return buffer;
        }
        //curl_easy_strerror was added in libcurl 7.12.0
        //cerr << "error: " << result << " " << curl_easy_strerror(result) <<endl;
        return "";
    }

    cerr << "error: could not initalize curl" << endl;
    return "";
}

int writer(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string *buffer)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (buffer != NULL)
    {
        buffer->append(data, size * nmemb);
        result = size * nmemb;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Below is the code for my main project CPP file for my Windows Forms Application "Code Viewer".  The includes work fine here.  I setup all the necessary paths for include and lib, etc.  I am compiling with /CLR (not pure):

```
// CodeViewer.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace CodeViewer;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the code of my Form1.h for the "Code Viewer" app:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#pragma once

namespace CodeViewer {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace std;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  OutputBox;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  AddressBar;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnGo;

    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

        //My variables
    private:
        System::String^ iAddress;
        System::String^ iSource;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->OutputBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
            this->AddressBar = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->btnGo = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // OutputBox
            // 
            this->OutputBox->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 80);
            this->OutputBox->Name = L"OutputBox";
            this->OutputBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(640, 228);
            this->OutputBox->TabIndex = 1;
            this->OutputBox->Text = L"";
            // 
            // AddressBar
            // 
            this->AddressBar->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 52);
            this->AddressBar->Name = L"AddressBar";
            this->AddressBar->Size = System::Drawing::Size(593, 22);
            this->AddressBar->TabIndex = 2;
            this->AddressBar->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::AddressBar_TextChanged);
            // 
            // btnGo
            // 
            this->btnGo->Location = System::Drawing::Point(611, 51);
            this->btnGo->Name = L"btnGo";
            this->btnGo->Size = System::Drawing::Size(41, 23);
            this->btnGo->TabIndex = 3;
            this->btnGo->Text = L"GO";
            this->btnGo->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnGo->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnGo_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(664, 320);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnGo);
            this->Controls->Add(this->AddressBar);
            this->Controls->Add(this->OutputBox);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Code Viewer 0.0.0.1";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

    private: System::Void MarshalString ( System::String^ s, std::string& os )
            {
                using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
                const char* chars = (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
                os = chars;
                Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
            }

    private: System::String^ curl_httpget(const string &url)
            {
                System::String^ buffer;

                CURL *curl;
                CURLcode result;

                curl = curl_easy_init();

                if (curl)
                {
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str()  );
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);

                    result = curl_easy_perform(curl);//http get performed

                    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);//must cleanup

                    //error codes: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
                    if (result == CURLE_OK)
                    {
                        return buffer;
                    }
                    //curl_easy_strerror was added in libcurl 7.12.0
                    //cerr << "error: " << result << " " << curl_easy_strerror(result) <<endl;
                    return "";
                }

                cerr << "error: could not initalize curl" << endl;
                return "";
            }

    private: int writer(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string *buffer)
            {
                int result = 0;
                if (buffer != NULL)
                {
                    buffer->append(data, size * nmemb);
                    result = size * nmemb;
                }
                return result;
            }

    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void btnGo_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 std::string myAddress = "";
                 MarshalString(iAddress, myAddress);
                 iSource = curl_httpget(myAddress);
                 OutputBox->Text = iSource;
             }
    private: System::Void AddressBar_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 iAddress = AddressBar->Text;
             }
    };
}
```

I am brand new to C++ and I am just learning how to build Windows Forms Applications so basically I don't know what the heck I'm doing.  I need to be able to call these cUrl functions from inside the Form1.h and I have no idea how to do this.  I want the "GO" button to execute a function call to retrieve the HTML source code of the URL typed into AddressBar using cUrl.  I have probably done in excess of 100 Google searches trying to figure this one out and I am hitting the wall.  I've been searching stackoverflow with the same results.  Always sorta kinda close but not what I'm looking for.  I'm sure there must be a way to do this.

Please be detailed in the response.  I probably won't understand a technical explanation that does not include some sample source code.

Thanks very much in advance!

---

UPDATE: After some more tinkering and tweeking of this code on the advice of Seth (see comments below) I was able to get my code nearly functional.  See the above edited version of Form1.h.  I still have one remaining compiler error, but I think I am close to understanding why I have that error.  Following is that error code:

```
c:\project\libcurl\visualstudio\codeviewer\codeviewer\Form1.h(137): error C3867: 'CodeViewer::Form1::writer': function call missing argument list; use '&CodeViewer::Form1::writer' to create a pointer to member
```

While my console app had no problem with this code it appears that calling the writer() function without parameters is a problem here.  Right now I'm guessing the solution is to feed it the parameters that it wants, but until I try that I won't know.  It's late so I'm going to bed.  Tomorrow I'll research the parameters needed for the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION...

Comment: Doesn't Visual Studio for C++/CLI come with a forms designer? If it does and I think it does, you can just drag a button on your form and double click the button which will take you to the `OnClick` event for the button and you can enter the code there.

Comment: Also if you're using .NET I'd take advantage of it and not use CURL. There are probably easier ways of doing what you're trying to do with .NET.

Comment: I understand the part about adding the OnClick event (that's pretty straightforward).  But I don't understand how to insert cUrl functions into that OnClick.

Comment: I really want to make this work with cUrl.

Comment: just declare your functions somewhere where the OnClick handler can see them, then call them in the handler, like a normal function. I'm not sure I understand what difficulties you're having. Also why are you set on CURL?

Comment: "just declare your functions somewhere where the OnClick handler can see them, then call them in the handler, like a normal function."  Can you provide a code example of this

Comment: Jason, copy and paste the body of your CURL functions above the click handler function and then call it in the click handler function like you have called it in your `main` function of your example code. You'd obviously not want to `cout` it, but just set the text of your rich text box to the result.

Comment: "Also why are you set on CURL?"  Because it has all the functionality that I need, including passing headers, and doing posts.  Eventually I want to build an app that can post to a secure online form using SSL.  This app is a primer for that.  Also, I know nothing about doing this with .NET.

Comment: "Jason, copy and paste the body of your CURL functions above the click handler function and then call it in the click handler function like you have called it in your main function of your example code." Questions: Do I need to ad the includes for CURL to Form1.h? Do I need to modify the functions to work there?

Comment: you need to just include the CURL headers, not stdafx.h or stdio.h or anything. You shouldn't have to modify the functions to work there either.

Comment: I get error messages galore when I do that.  There must be something I don't understand.

Comment: CURL isn't written for C++/CLI so it may not even be valid for that language. Remember that C++/CLI is a completely different language than C++. You'll probably have to learn to live with .NET.

Comment: CURL is a c library, but you can call it from C++.  I did that quite successfully with my console app (see code above), it's the windows forms app that's what's proving to be more complicated.

Comment: Yes I know, I've used CURL before, but like I said, C++/CLI is NOT C++. Things that work in one won't work in another sometimes.

Comment: That said, try including the stdio.h and stuff (not stdafx.h) like you did in your other project and see if that resolves any errors.

Comment: What about this line? "using namespace std;"

Comment: I continue to get errors.  Perhaps you might through me some example source code?

Comment: paste the errors you get on pastebin or some similar site. I have never used CURL with  C++/CLI before so I can't help you with any example code.

Comment: Seth, see my edit above.  I appear to be close to functional now.  Will check in again tomorrow.

Comment: Jason, your problem is that you've made the `writer` function a class member function. That means you can't call it without a pointer to the class to be the `this` pointer. Take the function outside the class so that it's a normal function, then change `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);` to `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writer);` (notice the added `&`)

Comment: Thank you Seth.  Your suggestions were very helpful.  I actually figured out I needed to move the functions outside of the CodeViewer class just before I read your comment, but I wasn't sure these functions were even able to coexist until you confirmed they could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED!!!  ;)))  WOOHOO!!  See solution below (Form1.h):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;
int writer(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string *buffer);
string curl_httpget(const string &url);
string iAddress;
string iSource;

string curl_httpget(const string &url)
{
    string buffer;

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode result;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str()  );
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);

        result = curl_easy_perform(curl);//http get performed

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);//must cleanup

        //error codes: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
        if (result == CURLE_OK)
        {
            return buffer;
        }
        //curl_easy_strerror was added in libcurl 7.12.0
        //cerr << "error: " << result << " " << curl_easy_strerror(result) <<endl;
        return "";
    }

    cerr << "error: could not initalize curl" << endl;
    return "";
}

int writer(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string *buffer)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (buffer != NULL)
    {
        buffer->append(data, size * nmemb);
        result = size * nmemb;
    }
    return result;
}

#pragma once

namespace CodeViewer {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  OutputBox;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  AddressBar;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnGo;

    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->OutputBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
            this->AddressBar = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->btnGo = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // OutputBox
            // 
            this->OutputBox->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 80);
            this->OutputBox->Name = L"OutputBox";
            this->OutputBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(640, 228);
            this->OutputBox->TabIndex = 1;
            this->OutputBox->Text = L"";
            // 
            // AddressBar
            // 
            this->AddressBar->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 52);
            this->AddressBar->Name = L"AddressBar";
            this->AddressBar->Size = System::Drawing::Size(593, 22);
            this->AddressBar->TabIndex = 2;
            this->AddressBar->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::AddressBar_TextChanged);
            // 
            // btnGo
            // 
            this->btnGo->Location = System::Drawing::Point(611, 51);
            this->btnGo->Name = L"btnGo";
            this->btnGo->Size = System::Drawing::Size(41, 23);
            this->btnGo->TabIndex = 3;
            this->btnGo->Text = L"GO";
            this->btnGo->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnGo->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnGo_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(664, 320);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnGo);
            this->Controls->Add(this->AddressBar);
            this->Controls->Add(this->OutputBox);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Code Viewer 0.0.0.1";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

    private: System::Void MarshalString ( System::String^ s, std::string& os )
            {
                using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
                const char* chars = (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
                os = chars;
                Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
            }
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void btnGo_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 iSource = curl_httpget(iAddress);
                 String^ mySource = gcnew String(iSource.c_str());
                 OutputBox->Text = mySource;
             }
    private: System::Void AddressBar_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 System::String^ myAddress = AddressBar->Text;
                 MarshalString(myAddress, iAddress);
             }
    };
}
```

As Seth stated above, I needed to move the CURL functions outside of the form class.  Then I had a string type problem because the CURL functions return a std::string and I needed the string to be a System::String^ for the form class.  The solution there was to use the MarshalString() function to convert the string retrieved by my CURL function from std::string to System::String^ before passing the value to OutputBox->Text.  The same also holds true for AddressBar->Text.  The solution above accomplishes all that and compiles clean with no errors or warnings.  Also the program does exactly what I expected it to do. :)